# Show S is a linearly independent subset of V

Tags: linear-algebra

$$V = {(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)\; | \;x_1-2(x_2)+3(x_3)-x_4=0}$$

$$S = {(0,1,1,1,0)} $$

Show that $S$ is a linearly independent subset of $V$. 
Proof: 
Observe that $0-2(1)+3(1)-1+2(0)=0$. Therefore, $(0,1,1,1,0)∈V$, and thus $S⊆V$. 
Let $a(0,1,1,1,0) = 0$. It follows that $a=0$. Since $(0,1,1,1,0)$ is the only element in $S$, it follows that S is linearly independent.

Is this all the problem is asking for?

Comment: are you sure this is what the problem is asking? Like you said, linear and one-element set is linearly independent...

Comment: This question is not write good. $S$ is not a set. S is a point. In order to $S$ be a set should $S = \{(0,1,1,1,0)\}$. And $V$ should be $V = \{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5) \in \mathbb{R} (\text{ or } \mathbb{C} \text{ or other sets}) : x_1-2x_2+3x_3-x_4 = 0\}$

Comment: With respect to the rest of the question. Yes, this is just what the question asks and your correct in your conclusions.